# KQL: merging 2 columns after joining tables

Tags: join, azure-data-explorer, kql

I want to merge 2 columns on which I joined 2 tables.
Here is my code:

```
let Table1 = datatable(ver: string, number:int) 
[
1.0, 5, 
2.0, 5,
2.1, 3 
];
//
let Table2 = datatable(ver: string, number:int) 
[ 
2.0, 3,
2.1, 2,
3.0, 1 
];
//
Table2
| join kind = fullouter Table1 on ver
| extend Delta = number1 - number
```

This is what I get:

[image]

And this is what I need:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could use the `coalesce()` function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/coalescefunction

for example:

```
let Table1 = datatable(ver:string, number:int)
[
    '1.0', 5,
    '2.0', 5,
    '2.1', 3
];
let Table2 = datatable(ver:string, number:int)
[
    '2.0', 3,
    '2.1', 2,
    '3.0', 1
];
Table2
| join kind = fullouter Table1 on ver
| project ver = coalesce(ver, ver1),
          Delta = coalesce(number1, 0) - coalesce(number, 0)
```

| ver | Delta |
| --- | --- |
| 1.0 | 5 |
| 2.0 | 2 |
| 2.1 | 1 |
| 3.0 | -1 |